# Диалоговое окно в MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Задача типовая: есть главное окно, отображающее некий список. Пусть это будут фамилии студентентов. После выбора студента и клика по кнопке "Изменить" необходимо отобразить модальное окно с информацией о выбранном студенте (ФИО, номер группы...) для последующего изменения. После изменения и клика по кнопке "Сохранить" модальное окно закрывается, а в главном окне отображается уже обновленная информация.

Собственно вопрос: как реализовать передачу данных между окнами, не используя code-behind?

Comment: А какой MVVM-Framework используется? Если знакомый мне, я мог бы запостить пример.

Answer (score 2):

Использовать сообщения. В одном окне (вью модели) выполняется подписка на получение определенного сообщения, а в другом окне (вью модели) выполняется отправка сообщения этого типа. Подробнее можно почитать в этой статье на примере MVVM Light Toolkit:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dn745866.aspx

Comment: Спустя время разработки с применением message'й, перестал их любить.
Сильно запутывают код, тяжело отследить состояние. Что-то вроде goto.

Тем не менее, так и не придумали достойной замены.

Как вариант, использовать реактивные расширения. Но тогда их нужно юзать везде. Например, конкретно для вопроса, можно в модальную вьюмодель добавить IObservable, который будет пушить измененных студентов

Comment: Написание программного обеспечения -- вообще сплошное принятие компромиссов :).